# Android: is there a way to receive the sms message from both SMSManager and the SMS receiver

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

Is there a way to receive the SMS message from both SMS Manager (default SMS application on android) and the SMS receiver.

I was trying to change priority and I can make any of these to get the SMS separately, but I don't know if it is possible to make them both to get the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you set your receiver to a priority higher than the default SMS app *and* call `abortBroadcast()` in your receiver, then the broadcast will continue down the priority list, and every app registered to receive the `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast will get it (unless one of those apps aborts the broadcast).

You shouldn't be aborting a `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast unless you've determined that the message is for *only* your app.